Open generic service type '[TRequest,TResponse]' does not equal open generic implementation type '[TRequest,TResponse,T]
Using net9 I have the following MediaTr Behavior:
public class ValidationBehavior<T1, T2, T3> : IPipelineBehavior<T1, T2> where T1 : IRequest<T2> where T2 : Outcome<T3>, new() {

  private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<T1>> _validators;

  public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<T1>> validators) {
    _validators = validators;
  } // ValidationBehavior

  public Task<T2> Handle(T1 request, RequestHandlerDelegate<T2> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

    List<Error> errors = _validators
      .Select(x => x.Validate(request))
      .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
      .Where(x => x != null)
      .Select(x => new Error(x.PropertyName, x.ErrorMessage))
      .ToList();

    if (errors.Any()) {
      T2 Outcome = new T2 { Status = Status.Invalid, Payload = new Payload<T3>(errors) };
      return Task.FromResult(Outcome);
    } 
    
    return next();
  
  } // Handle

Then I registered it using:
  builder.Services.AddMediatR(x => { 
    x.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();
    x.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(ValidationBehavior<,,>));
  }).AddBehaviors();

I get the following error when trying to get the service ValidationBehavior:
System.ArgumentException: Arity of open generic service type 'MediatR.IPipelineBehavior`2[TRequest,TResponse]' does not equal arity of open generic implementation type 'ValidationBehavior`3[TRequest,TResponse,T]'. (Parameter 'descriptors')

It seems MediaTr registration only accepts IPipelineBehaviors with 2 generic types:
  services.AddMediatR(cfg => {
    cfg.AddBehavior<IPipelineBehavior<Ping, Pong>, PingPongBehavior>();
    cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(OuterBehavior<,>));
    cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(InnerBehavior<,>));
    cfg.AddOpenBehavior(typeof(ConstrainedBehavior<,>));
  });

How can I solve this?
